# Regex for Tag Substitution on URLs

Tags: regex, validation, url, localhost, substitution

I want to know a way to create a Regex to validate an URL, but at the middle I can have a Tag for substitution, like this:

- `http://localhost/path1/path2/{SubstitutionTag}/path3/path4/etc`

Than I need a exception on my validation to except this Tag, currently I have this Regex:

- `^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$`

In addition I also need too except the word "localhost" on my URL.

Any tips?

Comment: The big class in your regex refactors into this `[\w!#$&-/:;=?@\[\]_~]` Note that when you put `\w` in a class it actually matches 138,770 Unicode V15 characters.

Comment: The latest URL Validator regex I have. Maybe you can modify for your usage. `^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I abandoned the idea of using only `Regex` to validate URLs and since my project is in C# I used a "mix" of `Regex` and `URI` to validate URLs and as a result I got this code:

```cs
private bool IsValidURL(string url)
{
    var validationPathCounter = 0;
    var tags = Regex.Matches(url, @"\{(.*?)\}")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .Distinct()
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var tag in tags)
        url = url.Replace(tag, $"validationPath{++validationPathCounter}");

    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
        return false;

    if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri tmp))
        return tmp.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || tmp.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
    else
        return false;
}
```

In the Source Code above, `Regex` is used only to obtain the paths between the slashes `/`, with them I can replace them with a valid path in order to proceed with the validations.

On the other hand, the `URI` is used to actually validate the URL, with it the `IsWellFormedUriString` and `TryCreate` methods are used, where the `IsWellFormedUriString` is the one who actually validates the URL while the `TryCreate` is used to verify if the validated `URI` is in `HTTP` or in `HTTPs`.

For my scenario, only these types of URLs were allowed, but if this type of validation is not necessary, then the `IsWellFormedUriString` method is enough, since internally it already uses `TryCreate`.

The Source Code above worked perfectly for me as it allowed me to validate URLs with generic parts of their path for future replacement and ensuring that the rest of the URL complies with the standards of an `HTTP` or `HTTPS` based URL.